# UBUNTU 14.04 The connection to ws://localhost:35729/livereload was interrupted while the page was loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, node.js, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to run a ruby-angular application. After installing node, npm, bower, coffee, js2coffee, grunt. I was able to run "BUILD=desktop grunt dev", and "rails s" from terminal. 
But it  shows a blank page.

**Terminal tab1**

*BUILD=desktop grunt dev*

```
Running "connect:app" (connect) task
connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
Started connect web server on 0.0.0.0:4000.

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

**Terminal tab2**

**rails s -p3000**

```
/home/chitresh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler.rb:315: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777

/home/chitresh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.10.3/lib/bundler.rb:315: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777

Faraday::Builder is now Faraday::RackBuilder.
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.12 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Thin web server (v1.6.2 codename Doc Brown)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

*When I hit **localhost:3000** in Firefox 38.0* 
Error displayed in firebug

> The connection to ws://localhost:35729/livereload was interrupted
>   while the page was loading.

*System specifications:*

> ruby 1.9.3-p448, rails 3.2.12
>
> node - v0.10.24, npm - 1.3.21, bower - 1.4.1
>
> UBUNTU 14.04

*And in Google-chrome Version 43.0.2357.125 (64-bit)*

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/gif: "http://getbarometer.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/barometer/images/transparent.gif".BAROMETER.load @ barometer.js:25(anonymous function) @ welcome:42

angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20…http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fscripts%2Flibs%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A170)

(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:6
(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:34
r @ angular.min.js:7
e @ angular.min.js:33
ec @ angular.min.js:36
c @ angular.min.js:18
dc @ angular.min.js:18
(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.js:3
n.Callbacks.j @ jquery.min.js:2
n.Callbacks.k.add @ jquery.min.js:2
n.fn.ready @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.js:2
(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.js:6
```